# how to combined gifs together to make a scene?

Tags: android, android-layout, animated-gif

I'm trying to make a gifs scene. I have scene about a girl moving (Walking, driving a car , running and sleeping). it is a fitness app and need to add this scene!. i already have the GIFs pictures but how to combined them together?

I want to create something familiar like this:
[image]

and this one

[image]

Comment: Show us what you've tried

Answer (score 0):

Actually You should not use Heavy GIF in App, it increase the size of App. You have to use Multiple Images and Use this Library to save your Code.[image]

https://github.com/Q42/AndroidScrollingImageView